# Adding YYYY-mm-dd to a hh:mm:ss timestamp in a CSV file

Tags: regex, sed, timestamp

Let's consider the following CSV file format :

```
server_name status_code timestamp probe_name
```

where status_code can be either I or E, and all fields are separated by tabulations

As an example, we can consider the following CSV line :

```
albatros.benches.com I 14:55:23.145 througput_probe
```

Every single CSV file contains a whole day worth logs. I'm trying to have all hh:mm:ss timestamps been prefixed with the actual YYYY-mm-dd, so that the resulting line would be as follow :

```
albatros.benches.com I 2013-02-25 14:55:23.145 througput_probe
```

As a bonus, since the CSV file holds the date (the filename is log_2013_02_25.txt) and since I have many of these files (for different days of course) to be 'sed'ed', I wish I could automatically use the filename as a seed for grabbing the suitable day in it and applying it in the timestamp transform.

**EDIT**: The filename is log_YYYY_MM_DD.txt, not log_YYYY-MM-DD.txt as described previously)

My sed and regex knowledge is rather limited. So far I'm using something like :

```
s/I^T/I^T 2013-02-25 /g
s/E^T/E^T 2013-02-25 /g
```

(^T actually is a ^V followed by a tabulation keypress)

on all of my files, but this really looks very awkward to me. If one day we add another statuscode (for example X), this trick will not work. I guess it would be more error prone to have sed handle the 3rd field, and prefix it. I can't figure out how to do this properly.

Any ideas welcome !

Thank you

Comment: Should date and timestamp also be separated by a tab stop or just by a single space? Also, is the status code the only field which is exactly 1 char long?

Comment: @speakr : the date and time are separated by a single space. The code field is exactly 1 char long yes ;)

Comment: Yes, but is the status field _the only_ field which is 1 char long or are there any other fields with the same length?

Comment: Sorry, misread. No there might be other fields being 1 char long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all your csv files are named like `log_YYYY_MM_DD.txt` you can try running this bash script in the directory where your csv files are:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in log_*.txt; do
    [[ $file =~ [0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2} ]] \
        && date="${BASH_REMATCH}" \
        && sed -E -i.bak "s/\t(E|I)\t/\t\1\t${date//_/-} /" $file
done
```

All status codes that should be handled can be put in the parentheses. E.g. to also handle status code `X`, just change `(E|I)` to `(E|I|X)`.

If you notice that everything works as expected you can remove the `.bak` to disable creating backup files.

Comment: Instead of `\t(E|I)\t`, you could use `\t.\t`, assuming that your "reason code" will always be one character, and that no other field is one character. (If you drop the `g`, then only the _first_ single-char field would match. I think that modifier is redundant here.)

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks for your input. Regarding the one char field I just asked the OP for further details about his csv data.

Comment: Works pretty well indeed. But the filename format actually uses underscores, which make the naming not so trivial (let's say beyond my bash/sed skills!).

Comment: @SCO I modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Perfect, I've just come through this date=`echo "${BASH_REMATCH}" | sed "s/_/-/g"`to sed the rematch, but yours is straightforward. Impressive. Thank you ! BTW, ${variable///} is a bash or a sed trick ?

Comment: @SCO If you are happy with the solution you may flag it as accepted answer. :)